# R studio box plot with 2 variables

Tags: r, boxplot

im trying to spice up my boxplot and have 2 variables in the same table, I have been searching all morning but cant seem to find the code i need

my table is laid out as

Levels Adult Baby

1 (distance for adult) (distance for baby)

1

1

1

1

1

2

2

2

2

i want a boxplot that shows the variety of distances at each level for adult and baby seperately?

Comment: Welcome to SO, s eadie 03! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages); sample representative data using `dput(head(x))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: https://r-graph-gallery.com/ is a good reference with sample code and data of multiple types of plots.